# Can I travel to Canada via land with expired US passport?

Tags: passports, passport-renewals

I will be traveling from Detroit to Niagra Falls, and then to Toronto for a quick 2 trip. (I live in Dallas and will be flying to Detroit) I have my passport which is expired but also have my State issued drivers license as well as my original Birth Certificate. Is this enough information to get by? I know they will probably give me some trouble but this was such a short noticed trip where i can apply for my new passport but won't get it in time for the trip.

EDIT: There are some questions on here like mine but are stating they only have their expired passport as i have more documentation than that. I am hearing some places that i will be ok as i have been a U.S Citizen my whole life and some are saying i will be denied.

Comment: My understanding is that your documents are sufficient for Canada but you might run into trouble because they do not suffice under US law (namely the Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative).  But the US cannot actually deny entry to a US citizen.  So it's not really clear what will happen.  If you try it, please come back and let us know what happens.

Comment: You might not be denied entry, but you can count on spending a few minutes or hours in a detention area. See [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/requirements/where-to-apply/passport-agencies/dallas.html) to get a passport within two weeks or less.